# C How to pass exact number of arguments in command line

Tags: c, arguments

I am learning C by myself, and I am writing a program that accepts commandline arguments.

```
main(int argc, char **argv)
chdir (argv[1]);
```

I was wondering, if there is any way I can limit the number of arguments that can be passed to this program, say, how much number of arguments I pass, it accepts only first 2 only? I was thinking of this because I don't want to keep a huge number of arguments in the program's memory(may be silly thinking).

Comment: argc is the number of arguments found. you can do `if (argc > 2) { ... exit with a "too many args" error ... }`. but does it really matter if more get specified? if your code only deals with the first two, what different does it make if the user specifies 3 or 3 million?

Comment: `"(may be silly thinking)."` - Yeah :)

Comment: Thank you Marc, Makes sense. But will it still store all the arguments until it reaches the `if (argc > 2)` ?

Comment: @pkill Yeah, it'll most likely store all the arguments until the code exits. but the trick is to not worry about it. It is the user's fault that happened, not yours, and we're talking about tens of bytes MAX. Unless you are on an embedded machine, it really doesn't matter. "Premature Optomization is the Root of All Evil" applies to memory usage as well (I'd argue especially, since memory is cheap these days)

Comment: Thanks MadScienceDreams. "Premature Optimization is the Root of All Evil"  Makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to limit how many arguments the OS can pass to your program programatically... however, you can do one of two things:

1. Ignore extra arguments
2. `exit` with an error.

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   #define EXPECTED_NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS (2) 

   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       if(argc != EXPECTED_NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS)
       {
           fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s (val)", argv[0]);
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }
       ...
       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
   ```

Comment: If you want to ensure 2 arguments, make sure you change it to `#define EXPECTED_NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS (3)`, as c will store the program name in the 0th argv, and EXPECTED_NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS (2) will only let you pass a single argument.